# Why is my Javascript App Script malfunctioning?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am just learning Javascript, and I don't know why my Google Sheets App Script is not working.  Do y'all have any suggestions?

I want the App Script to read a list of ingredients from column A in a sheet titled Ingredients. Then, I want it to compare the input String to each ingredient in column A and return the ingredient if it is found. I also want the return String to be sorted by the ingredient order (based on the given ingredient list) and to start with bullet points. It is currently either returning "No" or nothing at all.

```
function findHarshSurfectants(productIngredients) {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var data = sheet.getRange("A2:A").getValues();
    var ingredientsList = data.map(function(row) {
        return row[0].toString().toLowerCase();
    });

    var matchedElements = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < productIngredients.length; i++) {
        var ingredient = productIngredients[i].toLowerCase();
        var matchedIndex = ingredientsList.indexOf(ingredient);

    if (matchedIndex !== -1) {
        var position = "(" + (matchedIndex + 2) + "/" + data.length + ")";
        matchedElements.push(ingredient + " " + position);
        }
    }

    matchedElements.sort(function(a, b) {
        var positionA = parseInt(a.match(/\((\d+)\/\d+\)/)[1]);
        var positionB = parseInt(b.match(/\((\d+)\/\d+\)/)[1]);
        return positionA - positionB;
    });

    var result = "Ingredients found:\n\n" + matchedElements.join("\n");

    return result;
}
```

Here are other useful functions I wrote for previous versions of the function:

```
function capitalizeWords(str) {
    return str.replace(/\b\w/g, (match) => match.toUpperCase());
}

function existsInResult(value, givenArray) 
    { return (givenArray.indexOf(value) !== -1);}

function sortMatchedElementsByPosition(matchedElements) {
    matchedElements.sort(function(a, b) {
        var positionA = parseInt(getTextBetweenParenthesesAndSlash(a));
        var positionB = parseInt(getTextBetweenParenthesesAndSlash(b));

    // Handle NaN values (when getTextBetweenParenthesesAndSlash returns null)
    if (isNaN(positionA) && isNaN(positionB)) {
        return 0;
    } else if (isNaN(positionA)) {
        return 1;
    } else if (isNaN(positionB)) {
        return -1;
    }

    return positionA - positionB;
    });
}

function getTextBetweenParenthesesAndSlash(inputString) {
    var startIndex = inputString.indexOf("(");
    var slashIndex = inputString.indexOf("/");

    if (startIndex !== -1 && slashIndex !== -1 && startIndex < slashIndex) {
        var x = inputString.substring(startIndex + 1, slashIndex).trim();
        return parseInt(x);
    } else {
        return null; // Return null if the pattern is not found
    }
}

function checkStringInIngredients(inputString) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var ingredientsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Ingredients");
  
    var ingredientSheetNames = ingredientsSheet.getRange("A:A").getValues();
    var ret = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < ingredientSheetNames.length; i++) {
    if (ingredientSheetNames[i][0] === inputString) {
        ret = true; // String found in column A
        }
    }
  
    return ret; // String not found in column A
}
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide a Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) this way the community can have better understanding about your question and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function findIngredients(pi) {
    var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var list = sh.getRange("A2:A" + sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
    var matches = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < pi.length; i++) {
        var ingred = pi[i].toLowerCase();
        var idx = list.indexOf(ingred);

    if (~idx) {
        var position = "(" + (idx + 2) + "/" + list.length + ")";
        matches.push([ingred,idx + 2]);
        }
    }
    return matches;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Why did you do idx + 2?

Comment: Because data starts with A2 ... row 2 is the first row of data which is an idx of zero